# Find the source device of a FeedItem / FeedComment

Tags: chatter, salesforce1-app, connect-api

When looking at the Chatter Feed some posts or comments have the addition by what mobile device this post/comment was issued from.

[image]

I would like to query that device information via apex, but can't find any hint when looking at the FeedItem API description, or any related child objects. The information must be somewhere (because Salesforce displays it ;) ), the question is can I access it, and if so, where?

I thought about correlating the CreatedDate with a users login history, but this only works a.) for the last 6 months and b.) is not very "safe" in case a user uses both mobile and desktop device at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's available in the [clientInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_client_info.htm) field of the [ConnectApi.​FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_Feed_Item.htm) and [ConnectApi.Comment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_comment.htm) classes.

Comment: Well, I have to admit, I hadn't thought about Chatter API! Thanks!